# Serverless how to return 405 for unsupported HTTP methods

Tags: serverless-framework, aws-serverless

Let’s say I have a lambda function that `POST`s to `myPath` following:

```
functions:
  myFunc:
    handler: com.test.Handler
    events:
    - http:
        path: /myPath
        method: post
```

how do I provide a default error message for other http methods? When I make a GET on `/myPath` I get an ugly api gateway error. I want to return a 405 if anyone calls anything but POST on my endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out serverless have `any` option to pass for method:

```
functions:
  myFunc:
    handler: com.test.Handler
    events:
    - http:
        path: /myPath
        method: any
```

and then in your `Handler` you can check the method type and throw an error as you want.